# React native - rtl in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, right-to-left

firstly i worked on android and the RTL working good,
i added the following code:

```
   I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
   sharedI18nUtilInstance.setAllowRTL(context, true);
```

to MainActivity.java
and

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

to AndroidManifest.xml

and in the js code:

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
```

Now is the problem:
i tried to set rtl on ios but its not working
i added

```
 // in AppDelegate.m
   [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
```

and

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
```

in js code
but all the text and flex are still ltr...
what can i do?

Comment: try to set `writingDirection` to `rtl` , http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style

Comment: @Cherniv not working for me

Answer (score 8):

No need to add an RTL language to your project. just open your `AppDelegate.m` file `in yourProject/ios/YourProject/AppDelegate.m`

**take care not to open another file that similar to this with `.h` extension**

Now, add   `#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>`   to the top of code like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>      <-- added here
```

Now restart and rebuild your application.

Now you can change the RTL direction of the whole app with `I18nManager` easily.

```
import {I18nManager} from "react-native"


I18nManager.forceRTL(true) // false for LTR direction
```

Comment: i think this is the best solution. works on both ios and android

Answer (score 5):

My problem did not solve even by adding a new RTL language. Finally, I solved the issue by adding the following line to my `AppDelegate.m` file, inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, under the **allow RTL** line `[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];`:

```c
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES];
```

Comment: Nice solution dude!

Comment: but when trying set forceRTL(false);, it's still RTL..any help?

Comment: @MikhaMatta you can achieve this by storing a flag in persistent storage (e.g., AsyncStorage) to check if it's the first launch.

Answer (score 2):

in my case add

```
#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h> //in top page AppDelegate.m
```

and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add this in the top // page AppDelegate.m

```
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
...}
```