# How to Force React Native app to be just RTL?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-layout

I have an app is written in react native and all things in the app use "Arabic Language and layout"

So I want to force the app to be RTL & Layout too, so I use I18nManager from RN to do it and it's work fine in debugging version "when my mobile language LTR OR RTL it's work perfectly"

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry, I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

I18nManager.forceRTL(true);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

but when I release a apk version for play store when my mobile language RTL "Arabic" the layout and other things works fine, BUT when my mobile language be LTR "English" the layout changes and all of things

SO i want to force my app to be RTL whether the mobile language "Arabic or English"

Comment: you can check this out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps

Comment: it's from 2016! and i already check it but the issue is still!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

go to the file

> MainApplication.java
>   in this directory :
>   android/app/src/main/java/com/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

and add this code

```
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this,true);
sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true);
```

to the **onCreate** method there,
also dont forget to import this:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
```

Comment: @OliverD sorry i have no experience in IOS

Comment: This is the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: resolve for IOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592064/9161478

Answer (score 3):

That's because you didn't config the native side in android. Follow these steps:

1. Open this file:

   `android > app > src > main > java > com > PACKAGE_NAME > MainApplication.java`
2. Import `I18nUtil` package:

   `import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;`
3. Find `onCreate()` function and paste this snippet at the end of function:

```
public void onCreate() {
  ...
  // Force the app not to change on device locale change
  I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
  sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
}
```

Now when you change your device locale, the app layout wouldn't change!

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to restart your App using [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart) after forceRTL:

```js
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';


export default props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    !I18nManager.isRTL && RNRestart.Restart()
  }, []);
  return <AppContainer />;
};
```

Comment: Thank u I will try it later cuz i work in another project now :)

Comment: Hello @VahidAlimohamadi I write ur code in main file `App.js` and after the first time run the app, it's crashed

Comment: I try again ur solution but the first time I open the app it appears as RTL after the second opened its work as what I want LTR

Comment: Yes, @OliverD RNRestart not restart app in new RN or new Androids! It worked for me before. But now i use ```mansour-lotfi``` accepted solution.