# React Native Expo force RTL on LTR default system language

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, internationalization

I have an Expo application that is meant to be only in HE, and the RTL does not work in some situations.

On devices that use RTL system language, HE works fine, but when the system language is EN (or any LTR language), the application will be LTR on the first load.

So, my question is how can I force the app always to be RTL regardless of the system language?

Right now, I am trying to force it like this (this code is in index.js, I am using expo-router):

```
import 'expo-router/entry'
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native'
I18nManager.forceRTL(true)
I18nManager.allowRTL(true)
```

Also, I have tried to prebuild the project update the native files like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305153/react-native-rtl-in-ios/64592064#64592064), and deploy in test TestFlight using XCode, but did not work.

Do you have any other solutions?

L.E.

I have created a modifier that updates the AppDelegate.mm with suggestions from other posts:

```
#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>
```

and in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES];
```

So, I am not updating the AppDelegate.mm manually, but with the modifier in the expo prebuild - **Still not working on devices which has system language in English**

**Edit 2024, solution found:**

For me, I needed to add below code in AppDelegate
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"he", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of react-native-restart package to reload the app bundle in case of stuck.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to use [expo-updates](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/) but for some reason, did not work. I will give it another try if there are not other ideas